# iAd banner below tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, iad

I'm creating an iAd programmatically in my tableview application
I did the following in the `AppDelegate.swift` I wrote

```
import iAd
```

than I defined the proper variable

```
var bannerView: ADBannerView!
```

and I defined the properties of the banner itself

```
bannerView = ADBannerView(adType: .Banner)
bannerView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
bannerView.delegate = self
bannerView.hidden = true
```

Finally I call in my tableview controller the following

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
view.addSubview(appDelegate.bannerView)
```

with the constraints

```
let viewsDictionary = ["bannerView": appDelegate.bannerView]
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[bannerView]|", options: .allZeros, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[bannerView]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.allZeros, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
```

However the banner is fixed at the top and while I'm scrolling is disappearing underneath the view. Instead it should be always on top of everything.
Furthermore it's covering part of the tableview that is not visible.
How can I define that the tableview starts right below the banner or how can I move the banner below the tableview?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To load the banner on the top, just have a try with this one :

```
import iAd

class ViewController: UITableViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

var adBannerView:ADBannerView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

adBannerView = ADBannerView(adType: ADAdType.Banner)
adBannerView?.delegate = self
//Initialize the banner and delegate
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
return adBannerView
}
//With this func the adBannerView is the header of your tableView.
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: sorry but it does not work, it has the same behavior has my implementation

Comment: could you be clearer on "the same behavior as your implementation

Comment: what I wanted to achieve is to have the banner at the bottom of the screen and not superimposed to the table. Your implementation gives exactly the same result as mine, banner at the top and superimposed. I'm looking for the banner at the bottom and not superimposed it has to stay in front and the table has to scroll under it.

Comment: Okay, so in this case just reduce the height of your tableView and I'm going to update the code